# Solve a quadratic equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given

$$x^2+\frac{2D}{k}x=\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)$$

How do I get to

$$x=\frac{D}{k}\left[\sqrt{1+\frac{2C_{o}k^2(t+\tau)}{DC_{l}}}-1\right]$$

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Reduced_quadratic_equation and
factor out $\frac{p}{2} = \frac{D}{k}.$ (You must assume that $\frac{D}{k} > 0$, otherwise use absolute values.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have:
$$x^2+2ax=c$$
You could sum $a^2$ in both sides to obtain:
$$x^2+2ax+a^2=c+a^2$$
$$(x+a)^2=c+a^2$$
Then is the same:
$$x^2+\frac{2D}{k}x=\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)$$
Sum $\frac{D^2}{k^2}$ in both sides:
$$x^2+\frac{2D}{k}x+\frac{D^2}{k^2}=\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)+\frac{D^2}{k^2}$$
$$\left(x+\frac{D}{k}\right)^2=\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)+\frac{D^2}{k^2}$$
Taking root:
$$\left(x+\frac{D}{k}\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)+\frac{D^2}{k^2}}$$
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2DC_{o}}{C_{l}}(t+\tau)+\frac{D^2}{k^2}}-\frac{D}{k}$$
Taking factor $\frac{D^2}{k^2}$ in the square root:
$$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2D^2C_{o}k^2}{DC_{l}k^2}(t+\tau)+\frac{D^2}{k^2}}-\frac{D}{k}$$
$$x=\pm\left|\frac{D}{k}\right|\sqrt{\frac{2C_{o}k^2}{DC_{l}}(t+\tau)+1}-\frac{D}{k}$$
And if you assume $\frac{D}{k}>0$ 
$$x=\frac{D}{k}\left[\pm\sqrt{\frac{2C_{o}k^2}{DC_{l}}(t+\tau)+1}-1\right]$$
The positive ($+$)solution is what you want (it seems like you are solving a physics problem that could explain the choise of the positive solution)

Comment: Small error in the last line: if you multiply out you will get $\mp D/k$, whereas it should be just $-D/k$ as in the second last line.

Comment: I'm sorry now is fine?

Comment: Not sure if my browser is not refreshing properly but it still looks the same to me - the point is that the $D/k$ at the end of the second last line has a $-$ sign only, but in the last line it has acquired a double sign because of the $\pm$ at the front and the brackets.

Comment: yes! I corrected it

Comment: Looks good now!